# Не работает codeblocks на linux ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, codeblocks

Я только недавно решил установить себе впервые линукс. Проблема в следующем, при сборке выдает вот это :

> Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
> 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Установил xterm :

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install xterm

В пути  settings -> environment -> general -> terminal стоит xterm -T $TITLE -e

Но проблема до сих пор присутствует.

Comment: Что, где и как вы собираете? При чем тут xterm и codeblocks?

Comment: @VTT обычный консол апликейшн. Нажимаю кнопку ран и дебаг и выскакивает это сообщение. Написал xterm потому что видел в интернете как одно из возможных решений.

Comment: А Вы компилятор установили в систему? И все библиотеки для его работы (в бубунтах это ставится отдельным пакетом build-essential, если правильно помню)? В консоли (да хоть в том же xterm) можете откомпилировать свой файл?

Comment: @Vladimir установлен компилятор g++ вот полное сообщение об ошибках  g++: error: obj/Debug/main.o: Нет такого файла или каталога
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Comment: Это в логе в CodeBlocks? Тогда... Вы создавали проект? Указывали там каталог для хранения проектов? Судя по ошибке g++ не получает файлов для сборки. И еще раз - Вы пробовали компилировать Ваш файл в консоли, без помощи CB? Файл находится в домашнем каталоге? Права на чтение в каталоге с проектом (компилируемым файлом) есть?

Comment: @Vladimir спасибо огромное за помощь! Нашёл в чем проблема. Проблема была в том, что в пути была кириллица...

Comment: @DigitalResistance Что-то я сомневаюсь что проблема был в кириллице, в Ubuntu utf8 вроде по-умолчанию, нет ?

Comment: @vegorov мне лично помогло, всё работает :) А так не знаю, линукс впервые установил вчера